# basil cancer on outer ear-tight glasses maybe the cause?

Tags: cancer, glasses

Can tight glasses cut the circulation to the outer ear? Thus making the outer ear fresh oxygen blood starved and it then be more susceptible to basil cancer? i have currently been diagnosed with basil on the flap of my ear. I would bet that most of the people who are diagnosed with this kind of cancer wear glasses.

Comment: Welcome to MedicalSciences.SE! Please take the [tour] and read the [help]. For [reasons mentioned in this post](https://medicalsciences.meta.stackexchange.com/q/411) and in [ask], we require prior research information when asking questions. Please help us to help you and [edit] your question to provide more information on what you have read on this subject, what made you ask this question, and any problems you are having understanding your research.  If you found nothing, what did you Google? This helps to provide an answer which will be more helpful.

Answer (score 3):

First, it is basal cell cancer/ basal cell carcinoma (BCC) whose leading cause is generally thought to be from sun exposure/solar radiation (1).

Second, There has been absolutely no research into this hypothesis, nor could I find any research into circulation being cut off to ears and thus making them more susceptible to basal cell cancer. 
Do you have any research that suggests/supports your thoughts?

Here is a really great [summary paper](https://www.researchgate.net/profile/Miguel_Cordova3/publication/325241322_Basal_Cell_Carcinoma_Part_1/links/5bc0cafb299bf1004c5b023e/Basal-Cell-Carcinoma-Part-1.pdf) written for the Journal of American Academy of Dermatology outlining most of the history, presentation, typical costs and summary statistics (what we currently know) about basal cell carcinoma.

(1) Gallagher RP, Hill GB, Bajdik CD, et al. Sunlight Exposure, Pigmentary Factors, and Risk of Nonmelanocytic Skin Cancer: I. Basal Cell Carcinoma. Arch Dermatol. 1995;131(2):157–163. doi:10.1001/archderm.1995.01690140041006